# how to connect android studio to mysql with jdbc

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I've downloaded mysql-java-connector-5.1
and import it as library

the program is being compiled but no matter what i'm doing an exception is being thrown about connection failure.

i want to send data from the app(android studio-java) to sql data base which is stored in amazon(aws) and i want to get the data with raspberry pi(with c++).

the c++ works perfect.

with the android studio i canot connect, no to local host(mysql workbench) and not to aws.

i saw few templates on the web for the "url" parameter int the "getConnection" function, i used those:

for local host:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://<local ip>:<port>/<schema>
```

for aws:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://<endpoint given by aws>:<port>/<schema>
```

none of them work please help
this is my code:

```
public void test(View view) {

    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.17:3306/sys";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "password";

        //local verion - find ip with ifconfig/what is my ip website
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        // Do something with the Connection


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        Log.i("SQLException: " , ex.getMessage());
        Log.i("SQLState: " , ex.getSQLState());
    }
```

but conn always null.
did i forget something? 
* by the way im not sure if i have to use the

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

but i used it anyway.

this is the printStackTrace results:
System.err: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
08-10 19:26:58.223 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
08-10 19:26:58.225 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
08-10 19:26:58.227 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
08-10 19:26:58.228 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
08-10 19:26:58.230 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
08-10 19:26:58.232 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
08-10 19:26:58.234 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
08-10 19:26:58.235 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
08-10 19:26:58.238 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2267)
08-10 19:26:58.240 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016)
08-10 19:26:58.241 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
08-10 19:26:58.243 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
08-10 19:26:58.244 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
08-10 19:26:58.245 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
08-10 19:26:58.247 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
08-10 19:26:58.248 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
08-10 19:26:58.250 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
08-10 19:26:58.251 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
08-10 19:26:58.252 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
08-10 19:26:58.254 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.example.asaf.sql.MainActivity.test(MainActivity.java:45)
08-10 19:26:58.255 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-10 19:26:58.257 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
08-10 19:26:58.258 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
08-10 19:26:58.259 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
08-10 19:26:58.260 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
08-10 19:26:58.262 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-10 19:26:58.263 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-10 19:26:58.265 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
08-10 19:26:58.266 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-10 19:26:58.267 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
08-10 19:26:58.269 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
08-10 19:26:58.272 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-10 19:26:58.273 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
08-10 19:26:58.273 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
08-10 19:26:58.274 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
08-10 19:26:58.275 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
08-10 19:26:58.275 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
08-10 19:26:58.276 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:301)
08-10 19:26:58.277 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
08-10 19:26:58.277 20891-20891/com.example.asaf.sql W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221)

Comment: I have a stupid question: do you have a MySQL database server running on localhost that listens on 3306? And what's the exact error message you get?

Comment: this is the error: Could not create connection to database server. i know im running this through emulator so i even write the computer ip instead of 127.0.0.1. in addition i have data base in aws(amazon) and i cant connect. with the c++ it works and java no.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace produced by `ex.printStackTrace()`. You are currently basically ignoring exceptions. Just printing out the error and then continuing as if nothing happened is the main cause of your problem. Also, I hope you have downloaded a more recent version of MySQL Connector/J than the 5.1.0 version.

Comment: im not ignoring it just for the test, i cant pass the line of the getConnection(). and i want to download version 8 but i cant find there java-version-bin.jar like in version 5.1.0.   int version 8 i can find the same file but without the "bin" word and i cannot compile

Comment: i added the results of printStackTrace thanks for your resopnose

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example of a working method that connects to microsoft sql express

```
 try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://replacewithip:port//DBNAME", "User", "Password");       // Connect to database
            if (connection == null) {
                ConnectionResult = "Verify connection";
                Toast.makeText(activity, ConnectionResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //do something with your connection, in this case I executed a query
                ResultSet rs = null;
                String query = "EXEC AppMovil.INITE_Articulos_Familia '" + codigo  + "'";
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);


                //size = cantidad de rows, metodo para obtener cantidad de rows
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmtd = rs.getMetaData();
                while(rs.next()){
                    ListaConsultaFamilia item = new ListaConsultaFamilia(
                            rs.getString("Codigo"),
                            rs.getString("Descripcion"),
                            rs.getString("Precio")
                    );
                    listaConsultaFamilias.add(item);
                }

                listaConsultaFamilias.size();

                ConnectionResult = " successful";
                isSuccess = true;


                connection.close();
            }

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
   //catch error while reading
            Looper.prepare();
            isSuccess = false;
            Toast.makeText(activity, "No existen consultas en el periodo seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
        }
```